# Regeneration capabilities in humans?

Tags: human-genetics

To what extent can humans, (mammals in general), theoretically regenerate, and is their a way to speed up and/or exceed this original extent.

Comment: What do you mean by "theoretically"? Regenerate what? Toe nails, for example, are easily regenerated. Livers, less so. As it stands, this question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Regeneration - *or actions perceived as regeneration by popular culture* - depend highly on age and specific type of cells (epithelial tissue cells are a fine example). But you can't regenerate a leg-bone once removed.

But to get a more specific answer you to make a more specific question and define the terms you're using.